# How to use one button to edit and save using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have one button which I want to perform two different functionalities. First time when you click it enable text boxes and secondly when click, it must save the data and disable the all text boxes and change the name to original one.

Buttons name is Update and Save.

When you run the application for the first time, text boxes are disabled and the button name is called "Update" and when I click it enables all text boxes and changes its name to Save. This is working so far.

Problem is when I want to disable text boxes when I click "Save" it doesn't disable the text boxes. How can I save the data using this approach?

Code:

```
<input  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left" value="Update" onclick="EventChanger(this)" id="btnUS" />     

<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = document.getElementById("btnUS");

    if (elem.value == "Update")
    {
        elem.value = "Save";
                    
        $('#txtContactName').removeAttr('disabled', true);
        $('#txtIdentityNumber').removeAttr('disabled', true);
        $('#txtSuburb').removeAttr('disabled', true); 
        $('#txtCellNumber').removeAttr('disabled', false);  
  
    }
    else if(elem.value == "Save")
    {
        elem.value = "Update";

        $('#txtContactName').removeAttr('disabled', false);
        $('#txtIdentityNumber').removeAttr('disabled', false);
        $('#txtSuburb').removeAttr('disabled', false);
        $('#txtCellNumber').removeAttr('disabled', false);        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: whats your jquery version ?

Comment: Am using Javascript as you can see the function i am calling on the button

Comment: $ says that you are using jquery not pure Javascript.

Comment: i have checked one of the file its 2.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `prop()` instead of `removeAttr()` 
jquery official website :

> Note: Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr()
>   doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. To
>   avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead:

```
<input  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left" value="Update" onclick="EventChanger(this)" id="btnUS" />     

<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = $("#btnUS");
     if (elem.val() == "Update")
    {

       elem.val("Save");


        $('#txtContactName').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#txtIdentityNumber').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#txtSuburb').prop('disabled', true); 
        $('#txtCellNumber').prop('disabled', false);  

    }
    else if(elem.val() == "Save")
    {
         elem.val("Update");

        $('#txtContactName').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#txtIdentityNumber').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#txtSuburb').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#txtCellNumber').prop('disabled', false);        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Fantastic!, it is working fine. i have remove .removeAttr() . How am i gonna implement save functionality after updating ? I have no idea..still learning

Comment: for updating you should learn about Ajax here is a link for you [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) . please don't forgot to mark as answer if my answerd helped you. thanks.